# EE 1.6.x Module Development

Tags: add-on-development, module, ee1

So I'm returning an array of all the information I need from my function, but I can't seem to figure out how to parse through the array once I get to the template.

Module:

```
Class main{
 function data(){
      blah blah blah 
      return $array;
 }
}
```

Template:

```
{exp:main:data}{data}{/exp:main:data}
```

{data} returns “Array”

How can I parse through this in EE code or is there another to parse this variable?

I have also gone down another path which follows:

Module:

```
Class main{
 function data(){
      blah blah blah 
      $this->return_user(14);
 }
 function return_user($var){
      return '<p>'.$var.'</p>';
 }

}
```

Template:

```
{exp:main:data}{exp:main:return_user}{/exp:main:data}
```

{exp:main:return_user} returns `<p></p>`, but not `<p>14</p>`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EE 1.7 is pretty old but still fresh in my memory.

You need to use the global object $TMPL, which has a tagdata property that contains the data/string.

Example code

```
function data(){
    global $TMPL;

    $vars = array();
    $vars[LD.'data'.RD] = 'foo';
    $vars[LD.'data2'.RD] = 'foo2';

    $TMPL->tagdata = str_replace(array_keys($vars), array_values($vars) $TMPL->tagdata);

    return $TMPL->tagdata;
}
```

Comment: So like this:

`function data(14){
    global $TMPL;
    $TMPL->tagdata = $level;
    return $TMPL->tagdata;
}`

Because thats prints "Array" when I print out in EE code:

`{exp:class:method}`

Comment: You can't do it like that if $level is an array. You need to specify each variable one by one. Or do you want to parse out the array contents dynamically? is it a multidimensional array?

Comment: Ive changed it to no longer require an array. So $level is just a string.

Comment: Here is my two main methods. "data" works and returns an array, Im pushing the contents I need from "data" to Userlevel so that I can just call {exp:data:Userlevel} and return the string. 

http://pastebin.com/MNXPfPtn

Comment: Any have time to check out my pastebin?

Comment: See this revised version: http://pastebin.com/ipsm68Xj
This allows you do to:

{exp:data}
{UserLevel}
some more text
{Bio}
{/exp:data}

I also changed the UserLevel function to return data correctly.